# Gulp uglify breaking angular application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, uglifyjs

When trying to use `gulp-ugily` with my angular application, it is breaking, even though I am running it through `gulp-ngmin`.

Here is the gulp file:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    ngmin = require('gulp-ngmin'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('compress', function() {
    gulp.src('client/js/source/*.js')
        .pipe(concat('app.js'))
        .pipe(ngmin())
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('client/js'));
});
```

Comment: How is it breaking? Any hints from the error messages?

Comment: Argument 'myController' is not a function, got undefined. Basically a controller.

Comment: Wow, I needed to specify `client/js/source/**/*.js` is there a way to specify just search reclusively down?

Comment: Be sure you have defined you dependencies in a min-safe manner.  The should be in the braces such as : phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {...}]);.  See https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05  and scroll down the "Notes on Minification".

Answer (score 44):

It helps to disable the mangle option in uglify, for it's messing with all the injection stuff and naming.

```
.pipe(uglify({ mangle: false }))
```

Answer (score 32):

Maybe answering this for future users, as it seems the post is old.

Use ng-annotate to fix AngularJS problems when uglifying. Install it as any other library:

```
npm install gulp-ng-annotate --save-dev
```

And then use this in your gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp')
var concat = require('gulp-concat')
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify')
var ngAnnotate = require('gulp-ng-annotate')

gulp.task('js', function () {
  gulp.src(['src/**/module.js', 'src/**/*.js'])
    .pipe(concat('app.js'))
    .pipe(ngAnnotate())
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.'))
})
```

Hope this helped!

Source: https://medium.com/@dickeyxxx/best-practices-for-building-angular-js-apps-266c1a4a6917

Comment: I use this solution at work and it never failed me! Thanks @PhamHuyAnh!

Comment: yeah ! working answer. should be accepted as right answer.

Comment: It sounds to me a **better** solution because, the .js are more uglified than with 'mangle: false'  solution.

Comment: Note: If using ES6, you may get problems with ngAnnotate as it is no longer supported. For instance, adding an ES6 spread ('...') will cause a parse error.

Comment: I agree @Zymotik! The solution was valid for Angular 1.x in June of 2016!

This solution has to be revisited! =)

But, I think that webpacks have figured it out for many languages